# Can I make MoveWindow use screen coordinates in Windows 10? C++

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10

I wrote a simple utility that lets you move and/or resize any window on the screen by typing the new desired width, height, and upper-left corner of the window.  It works great on 100% scaling, but it fails when I change the scaling.

For example, on my 4k display, I have 150% scaling set.  `MoveWindow` treats my 3840x2160 display as if it is a 2560x1440 display.  When I tell a window to move to (1280,0), it moves the upper-left corner to the top-center of the screen.  I want my program to do that when I put in (1920,0) instead.  The problem with this is that I can still physically move the window to every single pixel on the screen. `MoveWindow` just loses access to the extra pixels that fall in-between.

Is there something I can do to force `MoveWindow` to ignore the scaling value?

Comment: Mark your app as dpi-aware and you'll be able to use real coordinates. See `SetProcessDpiAware`.

Comment: Thank you.  I had looked at that, but Microsoft's documentation didn't make that sound like what I needed to do.  SetProcessDpiAwareness sounded like a way for me to scale my UI elements and such.  I just wanted to move a window.  Since I intend to use this on Win7 and above, I used SetProcessDPIAware for Win7, but SetProcessDpiAwareness to PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE for Vista and above.  Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 2):

As IInspectable said earlier, the program did fail on Windows 7 until I made the following changes.  So far, this seems to work fine on Windows 7 through 10.

```
    if (IsWindows8Point1OrGreater())
    {
        HINSTANCE hinstLib;
        MYPROC ProcAdd;
        BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE;

        hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("SHCore.dll"));

        if (hinstLib != NULL)
        {
            ProcAdd = (MYPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "SetProcessDpiAwareness");

            if (NULL != ProcAdd)
            {
                fRunTimeLinkSuccess = TRUE;
                HRESULT ejHR = (ProcAdd)(PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE);
            }

            fFreeResult = FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
        }

        if (!fRunTimeLinkSuccess)
        {
            SetProcessDPIAware();
        }
    }
    else if (IsWindowsVistaOrGreater())
    {
        SetProcessDPIAware();
    }
```

Comment: There's also a way to mark your executable as DPI-aware by adding some XML to the manifest.  On newer versions of Visual Studio, you can also do this by setting the project setting for Manifest Tool > Input and Output > DPI Awareness.  The manifest version is generally preferred, since (I believe) it'll tag the process before other DLLs load.  For the application described, it might not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Potter was right.  All I had to do was set the DPI awareness, and then all of my MoveWindow calls worked at the true resolution regardless of which other program's windows I chose to move or resize.  I just added the following code to WinMain:

```
if (IsWindowsVistaOrGreater())
{
    HRESULT ejHR = SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE);
}
else
{
    SetProcessDPIAware();
}
```

Comment: [SetProcessDpiAwareness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302122.aspx) is supported since Windows 8.1 (not Vista). And you cannot call it like this either, because this requires that the import is resolved at load-time. This will fail to launch your application on systems, that don't export the symbol you are looking for. You need to use runtime-dynamic linking instead.

Comment: Yeah.  I found that out when I tried to run it on my Windows 7 box.  I actually changed it to dynamically load if Windows 8.1 or higher.